# Can I generate an Apple ID recovery key with Mac OS Mojave?

Tags: mojave, security, apple-id, two-factor-authentication

I have two-factor authentication enabled for my Apple ID.  I want to generate a recovery key in case I lose access to my 2FA devices/phone numbers.

Apple has a support article https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208072 which gives instructions for generating a recovery key on a Mac in system preferences. However, when I go to System Preferences > iCloud > Account Details > Security, there is no recovery key option.

[image: System Preferences screenshot of iCloud account security pane in Mojave]

Does this mean I cannot generate a recovery key with Mac OS Mojave? Is there an alternative method to generate a recovery key?